# have div side by side inside one big div, without using absolute position?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have a problem in my website

I have a big `<div>` with brown background and it has no height and have 3 `<div>` elements inside it, and that big `<div>` should not have absolute position.

I tried to fix that using `float`, but when I use float left/right that brown background is no longer visible!

Below is a simple code for understanding my problem :

```
<div id="bigDiv" style="background-color:brown"> 
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="midle"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your CSS as well.

Comment: create http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to float the elements, all you need to do is use `display:inline-block;`

As the float object basically means your box model loses it's height value as it no longer is relative to its parent. If you want to go the float method make sure you put a `<br class="clr-b">` where `.clr-b { clear:both; }`

Comment: i try this, it was good, but it not work for my first <div>!!!
how can i fix it?!

Comment: They would need to be in the floated div's not the overall div

Comment: i use it, it work carefully, tank you dear friend :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be causes of floating. You could resolve your problem by just applying `overflow:hidden;` styles to your big div.

Else, you could use [clearfix method](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=clearfix+method&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=F-CmUpWhFImlrQfusoHwDQ) (clear: both;).

```
<div id="bigDiv" style="background-color:brown; overflow:hidden;"> 
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="midle"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use floats:
http://jsfiddle.net/bKVuc/

```
#bigDiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#right, #midle, #left {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="bigDiv" style="background-color:brown"> 
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="midle"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

You can top float by using style:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the big `div` is floated with `height:auto`, the element should be floated in order to stuff the big `div`. Or the big `div` acts as if there is nothing in it(`height=0`), so the background disappears.

Comment: i now what happen in this case, but i can't handle it